# Winforms: Keyboard shortcuts for Winforms app hosting other applications in its panels

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms application, which hosts two PDF Viewers (Unmanaged C++) in its panels.

I want to have application wide hotkeys for project handling (Open,Save,Close,...) which would work even when users focus is on the hosted PDF Viewer.

I managed to achieve that via Winapi and RegisterHotKey, but client doesnt like that those are system wide (e.g. they disable the same MS Word hotkeys)

I did try to disable and enable global hotkeys on Form's Activate/Deactivate events, however those events appear even when i dont leave my own app, for example on top-menu entry or on a dialog-box.

Are there other solutions for application-wide hotkeys, that would work even if the focus is on the hosted application?

**SOLUTION:**

In the main Form, I handle Activated and Deactivate events like this :

```
public void PDFPicker_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var foregroundHwnd = GUI.winapiwrap.GetForegroundWindow();
        if (foregroundHwnd==this.Handle ||   this.OwnedForms.Any(form => form.Handle==foregroundHwnd))
        {
            if (!this.hotkeys.Any())
            {
                registerHotkeys();
                this.Text = "Hotkeys just registered";
            }                
        }
    }
    public void PDFPicker_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var foregroundHwnd = GUI.winapiwrap.GetForegroundWindow();
        if (foregroundHwnd == this.Handle || this.OwnedForms.Any(form => form.Handle == foregroundHwnd))
        {

        }
        else
        {
          unregisterHotkeys();
          this.Text = "Hotkeys off";
        }
    }
```

Then in the dialog, which is in the OwnedForms array, i call just this:

```
private void QuestionPostingPanel_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parent.PDFPicker_Activated(sender, e);            
    }

    private void QuestionPostingPanel_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parent.PDFPicker_Deactivate(sender, e);
    }
```

In case of more such dialogs, I would inherit AbstractDialog : Form, add those 2 event functions and a reference to parent, and then inherit all of them from this  AbstractDialog.

While registering/unregistering GlobalHotkeys, it was a problem for me when I tried doing that in parallel - global hot keys were bound to a thread.

Comment: Can't you check the active application and don't handle key-presses if you're app isnt the active window? Or use some timer polling to check the active window and disable the keyboard shortcuts if you're app isnt the active windows.

Comment: The first one would keep other apps hotkeys disabled ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So then check on Form Activate/Deactivate events whether the form is a foreground window or not (`::GetForegroundWindow()`) and then disable/enable hotkeys appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, this works in some cases. But sometimes I need to reopen the other app (e.g. notepad) several times to make its hotkeys available.

Comment: Now I figured out why :
I have a floating dialog (its a Form on my main form added with this.AddOwnedForm(..)) and when I enter my app into this dialog, it doesnt enable the hotkeys.

Comment: And when i leave the app from this dialog, it doesnt disable the hotkeys either.

I could check also Activate/Deactivate for this little dialog and operate the hotkeys within it, but it doesnt seem DRY to me if I had more such dialogs.